# Calculating sum in sql group by column

Tags: sql, oracle

```
book_id location seller daily_sales order_day    Type
 ABC      1        XYZ   100         2017-05-05   Y
 ABC      1        XYZ   120         2017-05-07   Y
 ABC      1        XYZ   40          2017-02-10   Y
 ABC      1        XYZ   60          2017-02-10   N
 .
 .
 .
```

I am  trying to calculate the sum of daily sales for each book_id. So basically in the above table, 
 for the day 2017-02-10 the sum will be 60+40. In other cases it will be only 100 & 120 respectively.

```
 SELECT book_id, order_day, (SELECT SUM(daily_sales) from facts groupby order_day, book_id, seller) as daily_sum from facts
 where location = 1 group by book_id, seller, seller, location
```

I think I am doing this incorrectly.

Comment: What is expected output ?

Comment: Do you need the output to be the same as the input table, with one additional column showing the total for the day? Or do you want a different format, showing only the `book_id`, the date and the total for each date? The first output can be achieved with analytic `SUM()` function, as in Vadym's answer. The second version uses aggregate `SUM()`, as in K. McCollow's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT book_id, seller, location, order_day, SUM(daily_sales)
FROM facts
GROUP BY book_id, location, order_day
```

Will get you the sum of daily_sales, for each combination of book_id, seller, location, and order_day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t.*
FROM
(
  SELECT
    t.book_id,
    t.seller,
    t.order_day,
    sum(t.daily_sales) over (partition by t.book_id, t.seller, t.order_day) AS result 
  FROM
    facts t
) t
```